# Per-user devices with AWS IoT

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, iot

Ok, so using the AWS IoT Thing Registry, you can list all your devices. But "you" means the AWS customer, and would list all devices registered under that AWS customer's custom endpoint.

But what if an AWS customer has multiple end users, that authenticate via e.g. Amazon Cognito Identity and they each have a number of devices. You would not want to have an end user list all e.g. thermostats of a specific brand/standard, but only the one actually registered to him. This is a use case I imagine would be very common, yet I can find no example in the AWS IoT sample code or documentation.

My only idea is to use a "UserId" attribute for each thing, and then filtering on this, when doing a ListThings on the thing registry. But how would you make sure that a user could only list his things, and not other users' things - an IAM policy per user?